# How to add gradient to UIView as an extension

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to add some gradient to a view in Xcode and for simplicity I tried to add my method as an extension to UIView:

```
extension UIView {
    func applyGradient() {
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.colors = [UIColor(hex: "F5FF8C").cgColor,
                           UIColor(hex: "F1F99D").cgColor,
                           UIColor(hex: "FDFFE0").cgColor]
        gradient.locations = [0.0, 0.5, 1.0]

        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    }
}
```

But apparently this doesn't work when I call it in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.myView.applyGradient()
```

Can someone point to me what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You aren't setting a frame on your layer so it probably has 0 size.

Comment: Oh I missed that, I have added frame size to be equal to self.frame.size, but its not showing anything differently

Comment: `gradient.frame.size = self.frame.size` doesn't work, by the time `gradient.frame = self.bounds` does, because the **frame** attribute contains both the location and the size of the view, and if you only get the size of the frame, even if you set the gradient's frame size, you do not specify the location of the gradient... so the gradient is never actually added to the view. I will edit the answer with this explanation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the question, you haven't set the frame at all. In the comment, your frame was not set correctly. This is the code that should work properly:

```
extension UIView {
    func applyGradient() {
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor,
                           UIColor.green.cgColor,
                           UIColor.black.cgColor]   // your colors go here
        gradient.locations = [0.0, 0.5, 1.0]
        gradient.frame = self.bounds
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    }
}
```

With your code:

[image]

With the modified code:

[image]

---

### Explanation

`gradient.frame.size = self.frame.size` doesn't work, while `gradient.frame = self.bounds` does, because the **frame** attribute contains both the location and the size of the view, and even if you set the gradient's frame size, you do not specify the location of the gradient... So the gradient is never actually added to the view. By setting the **frame** attribute directly to the **bounds** of the view, you also add the location of the gradient in the view.

Comment: It works, but for some reason, the gradient is applied for 80% of the view, the right part is not affected...the view is inside scrollview...

Comment: well, that's strange... Can you link to a picture or something?

Comment: May it be something related to your Constraints??

Comment: Looking over that... Please wait a few minutes

Comment: I fixed it, thanks, I had to call my gradient method inside viewDidLayoutSUbviews instead of viewDidLoad :)

Comment: Ok, you're welcome! If you have any further question on this, please ask

Comment: Is there a way to make the gradient horizontal?